# Passing List of Data to Other Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I have action Method in my controller which get data from the CSV file which I uploaded through web

I want to pass that data to Insert controller so data from the CSV will automatically inserted to tables in my DB and pass it to view

I'm using CSV HELPER, MVC

```
        public ActionResult ImportCSV(HttpPostedFileBase file, int compID)
        {
            var compName = db.CourierCompanies.Find(compID);

            string path = null;

            List<MyViewModel> csvD = new List<MyViewModel>();

            try
            {
                if(file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "upload\\" + fileName;
                    file.SaveAs(path);

                    var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(path));
                    var invoCSV = csv.GetRecords<ImportCsV>();

                    foreach(var i in invoCSV)
                    {
                        MyViewModel iCSV = new MyViewModel();

                        iCSV.CustID = i.cust_id;
                        iCSV.Fullname = i.fullname;
                        iCSV.CustComp = i.company;
                        iCSV.InvoiceNo = i.rec_no;
                        iCSV.InsertDate = DateTime.Parse(i.doc_dt);
                        iCSV.Road = i.w_addr1;
                        iCSV.City = i.w_city;
                        iCSV.Zip = i.w_zip;
                        iCSV.Phone = i.w_phone;
                        iCSV.Status = "BelumTerkirim";
                        iCSV.compID = compID;
                        iCSV.CompName = compName.CompName;
                        iCSV.StatDate = DateTime.Now;

                        csvD.Add(iCSV);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                ViewData["Error"] = "Upload Failed";
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Insert Controller

```
public ActionResult Create( MyViewModel model, int compID, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                    model.Image = ms.GetBuffer();
                }
            }

            var cust = new Customer()
            {
                CustID = model.CustID,
                Phone = model.Phone,
                CustComp = model.CustComp,
                Fullname = model.Fullname
            };

            var addrDet = new AddrDetail()
            {
                Road = model.Road,
                City = model.City,
                Zipcode = model.Zip
            };

            var invoice = new Invoice()
            {
                InvoiceNo = model.InvoiceNo
            };

            var stat = new Status()
            {
                Status1 = model.Status,
                StatDate = model.StatDate,
                Ket = model.Ket
            };

            var image = new Models.Image()
            {
                Image1 = model.Image
            };

            var detail = new DetailPengiriman()
            {
                NamaPenerima = model.NamaPenerima,
                StatusPenerima = model.StatusPenerima,
                TrDate = model.TrDate,
                InsertDate = model.InsertDate
            };

            if (ModelState.IsValid )
            {
                //customer
                db.Customers.Add(cust);
                detail.CustID = cust.CustID;
                invoice.CustID = cust.CustID;

                //addrDet
                db.AddrDetails.Add(addrDet);
                cust.AddrDetID = addrDet.AddrDetID;

                //invoice
                db.Invoices.Add(invoice);
                stat.InvoiceNo = invoice.InvoiceNo;
                image.InvoiceNo = invoice.InvoiceNo;
                detail.InvoiceNo = invoice.InvoiceNo;

                //status
                db.Status.Add(stat);
                detail.StatusID = stat.StatusID;

                ////image
                db.Images.Add(image);
                detail.ImageID = image.ImageID;

                //detail
                detail.CompID = compID;
                db.DetailPengirimen.Add(detail);

                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { compID = detail.CompID});
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: What is the expected workflow? User uploads file then is prompted with records and then clicks the button and the data is saved or just upload->save?

Comment: User click"Upload">browse file>Save (automatically inserted to tables in DB)

Comment: Can tempdata be used to store the data to pass list between the controllers?

Comment: Havent try it yet, but first does my code right? Get records from csv and inserted to viewmodel and then inserted to tables ?

Comment: "User click Upload>browse file>Save" - You don't need two action methods, just one i.e. `Create`. And CSV data will be read and returned from a private unmapped method. Or even better from a separate class that solely does the CSV stuff.

Comment: There is another feature which user can insert data manually too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abstract that business logic in another class and instantiate it inside your CSV action.

This way your can call your methods for inserting customers from both actions!

Comment: Sorry I dont understand, how to do that?

Comment: First of all, in your action Create check if your model state is valid in the beginning, so you can save some processing and return a message to the user!

Comment: You need to create a new Class, like "CustomerBusiness", inside that class you can create a method like "CreateNewCustomer" that accepts a MyViewModel as parameter. With that logic in the CustomerBusiness you can call it from your Create Action and from your ImportCSV Action!

Comment: @newbs with a little more source I believe it would be easy to provide a refactor example

Comment: can I pass data to post action method?